# Joomla 2.5 / Virtuemart 2.0 search custom fields

Tags: search, joomla, custom-fields, virtuemart

I am trying to solve this missing feature for virtuemart. The default joomla search or the virtuemart search modules do not look into custom fields of the products.

I did try to change the plugin for search as follows:

```
$wheres = array();
        switch ($phrase) {
            case 'exact':
                $text = $db->Quote ('%' . $db->getEscaped ($text, TRUE) . '%', FALSE);
                $wheres2 = array();
                $wheres2[] = 'p.product_sku LIKE ' . $text;
                $wheres2[] = 'a.product_name LIKE ' . $text;
                $wheres2[] = 'a.product_s_desc LIKE ' . $text;
                $wheres2[] = 'a.product_desc LIKE ' . $text;
                $wheres2[] = 'b.category_name LIKE ' . $text;
                $wheres2[] = '#__virtuemart_product_customfields.custom_value LIKE ' . $text;
                $where = '(' . implode (') OR (', $wheres2) . ')';
                break;

            case 'all':
            case 'any':
            default:
                $words = explode (' ', $text);
                $wheres = array();
                foreach ($words as $word) {
                    $word = $db->Quote ('%' . $db->getEscaped ($word, TRUE) . '%', FALSE);
                    $wheres2 = array();
                    $wheres2[] = 'p.product_sku LIKE ' . $word;
                    $wheres2[] = 'a.product_name LIKE ' . $word;
                    $wheres2[] = 'a.product_s_desc LIKE ' . $word;
                    $wheres2[] = 'a.product_desc LIKE ' . $word;
                    $wheres2[] = 'b.category_name LIKE ' . $word;
                    $wheres2[] = '#__virtuemart_product_customfields.custom_value LIKE ' . $word;
                    $wheres[] = implode (' OR ', $wheres2);
                }
                $where = '(' . implode (($phrase == 'all' ? ') AND (' : ') OR ('), $wheres) . ')';
                break;
        }
```

The #__virtuemart_product_customfields has a shortname pf i think too.

Any insight?